# vb.net web application gridview to gridview dynamic sql where clause

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, gridview

I have little experience of working with vb.net. My firm has asked me to work on developing a vb.net web application. I have two GridViews  on a form. On Gridview1 I get the data from DB menu table

```
select menu_name, menu_sys 
from menu 
where menu_sys <> '00' 
  and menu_grp = '00' 
  and menu_category = '00'
```

This gets the data in the GridView1 and displays it.

The part with which I am struggling is I want to (mouse)click on any row in GridView1 select the row, get the menu_sys value and use this as where clause to retrieve data for GridView2.

The where clause would be something like

```
select menu_name, menu_grp 
from menu 
where menu_sys = 'MY-SELECTED-MENU_SYS-VALUE' 
  and menu_grp <> '00' 
  and menu_category = '00'
```

I am not aware of how to add parameters at runtime to sql queries in vb.net. I am also not aware of where(which event) to write the above code logic in code-behind.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this `asp.net` or winforms application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the SelectedIndexChanged event. Here's an example:

Markup:

```
<as:GridView runat="server" Id="GridView1" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChaned"  ...
```

Code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChaned(Object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
   // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
   GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;
   var selectedId = row.Cells[1].Text; // assuming that the cell[1] has the id of the selected element

   //Now issue the second query and bind the data to the second grid:
   GridView2.DataSource = SomeMethodToGetTheDataUsingTheSelectedId(selectedId);
   GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Note: Don't call your grids "GridView1" and "GridView2", use appropriate names depending on the type of data they hold.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I just realized that you were looking for a VB.NET example. Take a look at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx